# Apply Different Resampling Method to the Same Column (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a time series and I want to apply different functions to the same column.

The main column is weight. I want to create a df that shows both the mean for the weight in the resampled period plus the max. I know I can do:

`df.resample('M', how = {'weight':np.max}, kind='YearEnd')`

`df1.resample('M', how = {'weight': np.mean}, kind='YearEnd')`

This seems inefficient.

Optimal:
`df.resample('M', how = {'weight': np.mean, 'weight':np.max}, kind='YearEnd')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
In [23]: df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,1),columns=['weight'],index=date_range('20000101',periods=100,freq='MS'))

In [24]: df.resample('A',how=['max','mean'])
Out[24]: 
              weight          
                 max      mean
2000-12-31  1.958570 -0.312230
2001-12-31  1.739518  0.035701
2002-12-31  2.503437  0.169365
2003-12-31  1.115315  0.149279
2004-12-31  2.190617 -0.087536
2005-12-31  1.286224  0.037669
2006-12-31  1.674017  0.147676
2007-12-31  2.107169 -0.064962
2008-12-31 -0.163863 -0.572363

[9 rows x 2 columns]
```

supporting how as a dict I don't think is too hard, will open an issue about this enhancement: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6515